# Smarty cookie name as variable

Tags: php, cookies, smarty

I have variable

```
$new = 'cookie_name'
```

now I need

use `$new` as cookie name in Smarty templates

something  like

```
{$smarty.cookies.$new}
```

but didn't work

Answer (score 2):

Is your cookie actually working? Try looking at the output of

```
print_r($_COOKIE);
```

Somewhere in your PHP file (obviously after the cookie initialisation).

Alternatively, try this in your template:

```
{print_r($smarty.cookies)}
```

Comment: Thanks, `{print_r($smarty.cookies)}` worked like charm.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `{$smarty.cookies[$new]}` ?

**edit:** try now: `{$_COOKIES[$new]}`

Comment: @jasne I'm  not that familiar with Smarty, thought `$smarty.cookies` existed, because you named it. Ok, try `{$_COOKIES[$new]}`

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign this variable to smarty like:

```
$new = "cookie_name";
$smarty->assign("new", $new);
```

Now you have `$new` in the smarty template:

```
{$new} or {$smarty.cookies[$new]}
```